# Disabling buttons in ASP.NET form, using onsubmit will not submit form

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a form like

```
<form runat="server" onsubmit="return disableButtons()">
  <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" />
  <asp:FileUpload ID="uplNewFiles" runat="server" AllowMultiple="True" />
  <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Add file" OnClick="OnAddFilesToApplicationClick"/>
</form>
```

and a script like

```
function disableButtons()
{
  var buttons = $("input[type=submit]");
  buttons.prop("disabled", true);

  return true;
}
```

Having this onsubmit handler prevents the form from submitting.

Why?

Comment: `buttons` variable not defined

Comment: check your console for errors

Comment: @Pedram Woops, omitted the definition, question updated.

Comment: What happens when you click your button? Is the server side code being called or do you get an exception?

Comment: Client side events will be called prior to the server side, since you are disabling the button at client side may be it is preventing the click function on that button.

Comment: @Bharadwaj how could that be, since a) we're handling the "submit" event here, so not directly related to the button click, and b) even if it were related, the event has already happened, so disabling the button would be too late to stop that.

Comment: @ADyson Which event will be triggered first? `onsubmit` or button's `OnClick`?

Comment: @Marco The buttons gets disabled but nothing more happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery form submit

```
<form runat="server" method="POST" action="/youraction" id="myForm">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="uplNewFiles" runat="server" AllowMultiple="True" />
    <asp:Button id="myBtn" type="button" runat="server" Text="Add file"/>
</form>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#myBtn').click(function(){
          $('#myBtn').prop('disabled',true);
          $('#myForm').submit();
     });
});
<script>
```